# Is it reasonable to deploy PCoIP for 1 to 1 configurations?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access, pcoip

I frequently need to connect from my laptop at remote locations back to my primary work PC.  I've been using Remote Desktop for this (over VPN of course).  It's usable, but I'd like better performance.  I'm very impressed with the performance of thin clients using PCoIP back to servers.  Are there any free to use options to turn my PC into a PCoIP server and my laptop into a PCoIP client?

Side note: My searching reveals there are a LOT of VNC fans on here.  I've already tried that and the performance is worse than Remote Desktop.  I'm also familiar with NoMachine (I've used it for *nix terminal servers before), but that doesn't appear to have a Windows version.

Comment: Most ThinClients that I've used were over a local LAN - not remote/over the internet. Is PCoIP significantly better than RDP over Internet connections?

Comment: Based on the rate limited demos I've seen, PCoIP is significantly better in low bandwidth conditions compared to RD.  I've not seen demos that can accurately simulate latency, but based on the protocol design, I still expect it to be superior with the high latency of a remote connection as well.  **edit**  Actually, I have.  At a VMUG meeting awhile back one of the guys did actually do PCoIP back to his home office (on the other side of the USA) and it was better than I get over RD in the same city (which might require a Chicago hop anyways).

Comment: How is the performance not adequate?

Comment: Slow screen re-draws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDP 8.1 is competitive with PCoIP now.  I'll be sticking with RDP for now as all the PCoIP solutions seem to involve considerable expense.